# Как сказать системе, какие части окна являются клиентскими, а какие нет?

Tags: windows, winapi

Как сказать системе, какие части окна являются клиентскими, а какие нет?

Comment: Можно сформулировать вопрос иначе? Что, собственно, имеется в виду? Что значит открыть клиентскую облась окна (где бы-то ни было)?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно отрабатывать сообщения Windows. Чтобы сказать, что конкретная точка лежит в неклиентской области окна, надо обработать сообщения вида (WM_NCXXX), например:

- WM_NCPAINT - отрисовка,
- WM_NCCALCSIZE - расчет координат области,
- WM_NCHITTEST - принадлежность области (рамка, заголовок и т.п.).

Получение сообщений идет через WindowProc. Полный список сообщений есть в MSDN.